# Objective-C: "Casting a struct"

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting, struct

I need to find a way to tell the C compiler of my program that a certain structure is the same as the other structure (they are identical in definition). I figured casting would be decent enough, but maybe its not a good idea?

The reason that I am not just using one struct is because the structs are defined in very heavy framework classes and I have a lot of different classes of my own importing the class that requires the use of the structure in it's `.h`.

So, how can I tell the compiler that `Struct A` can be used for a function requiring `Struct B`, given that they are identical, if it is even possible?

---

To make this very specific, in my case, I have a singleton that is accessed and utilized by around 14 classes. Some of the functions in the singleton work alongside the other classes and provide resources and data for their specific imports. One of which is the MapKit framework. There are a number of structs within the MapKit framework that I have been utilizing (especially MKUserLocation.h), but will import a number of other classes and add on a lot to the definition.

A specific example for me is using CLLocationCoordinate2D, which I have had to recreate in my singleton so that not all 14 classes import from the MapKit framework. It just seems excessive.

I know how to make this all work, but there should be a good solution to this other than casting or importing to everything.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the same struct. I see you explain they are different, but it might be the most elegant solution. Otherwise create a function that copies the struct (less elegant) or an adapter.

Comment: Use conditional definition. Do not define your version if the other one has been defined for that file. Define yours, with the same name when the other one is not defined.

Comment: If everything else is broken, you can always resort to `*(struct OtherStruct *)&variable`, but that's a hack (and I'm not sure it's not UB anyways).

Comment: @H2CO3 Thats what I thought to use, but it DOES seem very hackish.

Comment: @RileyE Nevermind the BSD sockets API uses it extensively... -.-"

Comment: @QuentinUK Its not a matter of that, the definition is out of my control, as it is in a library file and only one or two classes actually import it.

Comment: @hd1 As I stated in my question, I've tried casting.

Comment: and what was the result of casting?

Comment: @RileyE also try typedeffing your own structure type to the external library's one.

Comment: @hd1 I suspect a syntax error, you can't cast structures like that.

Comment: @dmaij I couldn't create a function that switches them, unless if I wrote it specific for each file, since they can't "see" each other.

Comment: @H2CO3 I would love to do that, but where the struct is defined, it cannot "see" the library's struct.

Comment: @RileyE ***Warning: Design problem spotted!***

Comment: @RileyE, That's not quite what i meant. I meant a global helper function with the format struct a convert (struct B) and vice versa.

Comment: @H2CO3 ***Houston, please give status of problem.***

Comment: @dmaij These classes are in different files. I'm not sure how it would see a global function. And if there was a way, it would return, or accept types that those classes don't understand.

Comment: @RileyE I mean, if you can't simply `#include <library.h>` into the file you're typedeffing your own struct, you should probably reorganize your code in order to be able to do so.

Comment: #incude "global functions.h"

Comment: I guess I will just have to cast it. There is absolutely no way that I am importing a number of files into the .h of the core singleton (which I need, since everything intermixes), which will then import all of those library files and it's contents into many other classes throughout the project. Thanks for the suggestions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply write a global function to convert from one struct to another?

```
void OneStructToAnotherStruct( struct FromStruct* from, struct ToStruct* to )
{
   to->x = from->x;
   to->y = from ->y;
   to->z = from->z;
}
```

Comment: Global as in where? If you truly mean a global function, then I'm supposed to use implicit declaration when I use it?

Comment: so, one struct is from an imported library that you are making calls into and the other is defined by your code?  I'm not understanding.

Comment: Yes. I have to define one myself, because I cannot import the library class that originally defines it. That means that a couple of classes have access to both.

Comment: How can you have classes that access both but not link in the defined structure?  It sounds like a redesign is in order.  This will bite you in the future.  Even if you figure out a way to fool the compiler, if you have to fool the compiler it screams of poor design.

Comment: Its definitely not poor design. Its poor design to just import everything all the time. I don't know how else to explain it other than there is a central class that doesn't need access to all of the libraries, but just a couple structs, so it defines it's own. Some other classes utilize the libraries, so they import them. The core singleton class needs to be utilized by a number of different classes for a number of different reasons because all of the data intermixes. Its a large and complex system, so I guess its hard to explain. The core only computes, rather than using the library.

Comment: The interface that is highly depended upon should not be inter-mixed with other functionality that you don't need and don't want to bring in.  It's poor design from that standpoint.  It seems like the struct you need should have been defined in such a way that you wouldn't need to bring in the world.  I'm not saying it's your poor design.  ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21154/discussion-between-rileye-and-bejmax)